# Left adjoint to Double Nerve?

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff

The well known nerve functor from small categories to simplicial sets has a left adjoint, namely the fundamental category functor. Does the double nerve functor $N^2:2Cat\rightarrow sSSet$ from 2-categories to bisimplicial sets have a similar left adjoint? I think I've seen a vague reference to it somewhere but nothing explicit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, by the adjoint functor theorem, because it preserves all limits and both categories are locally presentable.  It's also an instance of the general notion of [nerve and realization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+and+realization) determined by a canonical cobisimplicial 2-category.